# Question on showing that if $g^{v(nm)}\equiv g^{v(n)}g^{v(m)} $ mod $q$ then $v(nm)=v(n)+v(m)$ mod $q-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

Let $q$ be a prime and let the primitive root $g$ mod $q$, i.e. $g, g^2 , \dots, g^{q-1}$ gives all the elements of $(Z/qZ)^*$. For some fixed such $g$, let $v(n)$, $(n,q)=1$ be the unique element from ${1,2,\dots, q-1}$ such that $g^{v(n)}\equiv n $ mod $q$.

Then $v(1)=q-1$ by Fermat's Little theorem. Now we define different Dirichlet characters mod $q$, by $$n \mapsto e^\frac{{2\pi ikv(n)}}{q-1}$$ for each $1\le k \le q-1$. These functions are Dirichlet characters because $g^{v(nm)}\equiv g^{v(n)}g^{v(m)}$ mod $q$.

Then why do we get $v(nm)=v(n) + v(m)$ mod $q-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $v(n) + v(m) = a(q-1) + r$ then it is clear that $$g^{r} = g^{v(n) + v(m) - a(q-1)} = g^{v(n)}g^{v(m)}g^{-a(q-1)} = nm \;\text{mod}\; q$$ by uniqueness: $$v(nm) = r$$

Comment: Sorry I don't follow this proof. Why is $g^r = nm $ mod $q$ and then why does $v(nm)=r $ gives $v(nm)=v(n)+v(m)$ mod $q-1$?

Comment: Sorry I had a small mistake and I fix it.